# How to use css to implement same effect as having a <br> inside target element?

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

I want all empty `<p>` elements in html to have a line break inside it, and use css to make this effect.

Details:

Both of the `p` tags below should have same appearance (across browsers and zoom levels)

All other customs styles of `p` tags are same

```css
p:empty {
  /** How can I code here (or some other way css codes can achieve this) **/
}
```

```html
<p><br></p>
<p></p>
```

background: I want to show preview of the editing content inside prosemirror editor, while the editor doesn't preserve `<br>` inside `<p>` when serialize the content to `json` and make it look different when preview rendered from `json`. see: [discuss.prosemirror](https://discuss.prosemirror.net/t/how-to-preserve-br-tags-in-empty-paragraphs/2051/3?u=djy)

Comment: :empty will not work if anything is in <p> tag, try to explain your question in more details. if possible try to give us visual what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: I assume you’re trying to do this to create equal spacing somewhere? A line break is a html element that is not a fixed height - it depends on other factors including line height and whether it has any styling of its own. There is no easy way to try replicate the behaviour of a html element in CSS. Tell us what exactly are you trying to achieve, and maybe we can give a better solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's several ways you could do this, here's how you could it using the same logic behind your own code by simply adding a space Unicode after it's content :

```css
p:empty:after {
  content: '\00a0';
}

p {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p><br></p>
<p></p>
```

To demonstrate :

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("first").offsetHeight)
console.log(document.getElementById("second").offsetHeight)
```

```css
p:empty:after {
  content: '\00a0';
}
p {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p id="first"><br></p>
<p id="second"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

An empty inline-block element can also do the job:

```css
p:empty:after {
  content: '';
  display:inline-block;
}

p {
  outline:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p><br></p>
<p></p>

<div style="font-size:30px">
<p><br></p>
<p></p>
</div>
```

Or like below:

```css
p:empty:after {
  content: ' ';
  white-space:pre;
}

p {
  outline:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p><br></p>
<p></p>

<div style="font-size:30px">
<p><br></p>
<p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I tested this, but there is still some different in the appearance. currently `content: '\00a0'` is the only working approach.

Comment: @dongjy you have probably more CSS involved, as you can test in the snippet both produce the same output

Comment: The god of CSS has spoken, so a +1 I shall give

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, the second solution does work, but not the first. After research I found something very strange: you can create a new html and copy & paste `inline-block` solution (the first one) code into it and then open the html file with browser to see the different layout from the one produced by click *run code snippet* button below this snippet. The empty `<p>` has zero height in both firefox & chrome. Can you figure out why the difference?

Comment: @dongjy are you declaring the doctype on the top of your file?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you, add `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of html file then both solutions work. You are a master.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `<p>` an explicit `height` and `line-height` like this:

```
p {
  height: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
table, tr, th, td {
  border: 1px solid rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

p {
  height: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  <th>Column 1</th>
  <th>Column 2</th>
  </thead>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <p></p>
      <p>Two</p>
      <p></p>
      <p>Four</p>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <p><br></p>
      <p>Two</p>
      <p><br></p>
      <p>Four</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I test this, there is still some different in the appearance, may `<br>` not exactly `1em` as of `line-height` and `height` ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct @dongjy - as I said above, the line height for the `p` tag influences the display height and different paragraphs could have different lineheight set by different selectors in CSS.